# Don't show ExitDlg in wix after successful installation

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, wix

I have developed the installer using WIX and created bootstraper project to include other dependencies.Application is installing without issue.After installation,it is showing the success dialog and after user click `Close` the dialog closes.I want to remove or hide that dialog after application installation.I have taken the source code of wix and added the `ExitDialog.wxs` to my project.

ExitDialog.wxs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  <copyright file="ExitDialog.wxs" company="Outercurve Foundation">
    Copyright (c) 2004, Outercurve Foundation.
    This software is released under Microsoft Reciprocal License (MS-RL).
    The license and further copyright text can be found in the file
    LICENSE.TXT at the root directory of the distribution.
  </copyright>
-->
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>
        <UI>
            <Dialog Id="ExitDialog" Width="370" Height="270" Title="!(loc.ExitDialog_Title)">
                <Control Id="Finish" Type="PushButton" X="236" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Default="yes" Cancel="yes" Text="!(loc.WixUIFinish)" />
                <Control Id="Cancel" Type="PushButton" X="304" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Disabled="yes" Text="!(loc.WixUICancel)" />
                <Control Id="Bitmap" Type="Bitmap" X="0" Y="0" Width="370" Height="234" TabSkip="no" Text="!(loc.ExitDialogBitmap)" />
                <Control Id="Back" Type="PushButton" X="180" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Disabled="yes" Text="!(loc.WixUIBack)" />
                <Control Id="BottomLine" Type="Line" X="0" Y="234" Width="370" Height="0" />
                <Control Id="Description" Type="Text" X="135" Y="70" Width="220" Height="40" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes" Text="!(loc.ExitDialogDescription)" />
                <Control Id="Title" Type="Text" X="135" Y="20" Width="220" Height="60" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes" Text="!(loc.ExitDialogTitle)" />
                <Control Id="OptionalText" Type="Text" X="135" Y="110" Width="220" Height="80" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes" Hidden="yes" Text="[WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALTEXT]">
                    <Condition Action="show">WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALTEXT AND NOT Installed</Condition>
                </Control>
                <Control Id="OptionalCheckBox" Type="CheckBox" X="135" Y="190" Width="220" Height="40" Hidden="yes" Property="WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOX" CheckBoxValue="1" Text="[WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOXTEXT]">
                    <Condition Action="show">WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOXTEXT AND NOT Installed</Condition>
                </Control>
            </Dialog>

            <InstallUISequence>
                <Show Dialog="ExitDialog" OnExit="success" Overridable="yes" />
            </InstallUISequence>

            <AdminUISequence>
                <Show Dialog="ExitDialog" OnExit="success" Overridable="yes" />
            </AdminUISequence>
        </UI>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

What values should i change `ExitDialog.wxs` to hide the `ExitDlg` dialog. Need help to solve this.

Comment: It sounds like you don't want any exit dialog at all. If that's the case, then just don't include it in the `InstallUISequence` or `AdminUISequence`. (and obviously, you don't need the ExitDialog definition...)

Comment: @LynnCrumbling I commented  InstallUISequence or AdminUISequence still i can see the "ExitDlg" after installation.Do i need to refer the included "ExitDialog.wxs" file in bundle.wxs.Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

It's enough to add following code to suppress exit dialog.
You don't need to copy dialog.

```
        <InstallUISequence>
            <Show Dialog="ExitDialog" OnExit="success">0</Show>
        </InstallUISequence>

        <AdminUISequence>
            <Show Dialog="ExitDialog" OnExit="success">0</Show>
        </AdminUISequence>
```

This way you are overriding same declaration from snippet you have posted from original design with condition that is never met (0).